# disableAutoPrimitive in wso2esb 4.8.1

Tags: json, soap, wso2, wso2-esb

how can I configure a regex in wso2esb 4.8.1 to have a specific long number be translated as a string when going from soap to json? I tried:

```
synapse.commons.json.disableAutoPrimitive.regex=^\d{20}$
```

and

```
synapse.commons.json.output.disableAutoPrimitive.customReplaceRegex=^\d{20}$
```

in synapse.properties, but that does not work.

Answer (score 1):

This seems fixed in ESB next version according to https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-4781.

Comment: But https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/JSON+Support (near bottom of page) states that this should already be possible in 4.8.1?